# Does TCL containg built in functions of type get_bits and set_bits?

Tags: tcl, bit

The get_bits will return specific bits of a value and set_bits will set specific bits of a value to a specified value. Does TCL contain such functions built in or should they be written by the user?

The binary scan command does come close to the get_bits function but is not the same thing.

Comment: What are the signatures of those functions? What are the return values?

Answer (score 2):

There's no specific function for getting or setting a particular bit. We can make them.

```
proc get_bit {value bit} {
    expr {($value & (1 << $bit)) != 0}
}

proc set_bit {varName bit {value 1}} {
    upvar 1 $varName var
    if {$value} {
        set var [expr {$var | (1 << $bit)}]
    } else {
        set var [expr {$var & ~(1 << $bit)}]
    }
}
```

Those will work with integer values of any width; you're not restricted to 32 bits or 64 bits.

```
# Lots of bits!
set x 123456789012345678901234567890

# Fetch a particular bit
puts [get_bit $x 17]
# Set a bit to 1
set_bit x 78
puts "x = $x"
# Set a bit to 0
set_bit x 75 0
puts "x = $x"
```

Comment: what about get_bits and set_bits i.e multiple bits rather than just a single bit

Comment: @quantum231 You can write your own based on the provided single bit code?